# UAV classification

Tags: aircraft, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Is there a classification for UAVs? And based on the specs below, what type of UAV can that be classed as please?

```
Max cruise velocity: 217mph (350km/hr)
Max cruise altitude: 2km 
Range: 500km
Mass of payload: 100kg
Fixed wing
```

Thanks, any resources with classification would be appreciated too
(No specific country)

Comment: This may differ based on local regulation. Is there a specific country you're asking about?

Comment: Medium Altitude Long Endurance??

Comment: @Pilot, definitely not MALE, the altitude is quite Low, and no info on Endurance.

Answer (score 1):

For Europe, EASA (the European Union Aviation Safety Agency) classifies UAVs /  UAV operations into three categories based on risk, which in turn depend on the weight and capabilities of the UAVs. Any UAV with MTOW over 25 kg will be in the "specific" or "certified" category.

More info here: https://www.easa.europa.eu/the-agency/faqs/drones-uas

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has some [drone classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_aerial_vehicle#Based_on_the_weight), based on weight, altitude and degree of autonomy. 100Kg and 2km would be 'medium' or (rather strangely) 'NATO type' (which is slightly lower than 'tactical'.

And the US military also have their own [drone classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._military_UAS_groups). This would be 'group 3'.

Comment: good links. The mass of "payload" is 100kg, so the aircraft MTOW is possibly much larger (500+kg?)